# Scale font-size by height but limit it to the viewports width

Tags: css, sass

I am looking for a way to have the font-size based on the viewports height, but with the exception that the value should not exceed the viewports current width.

```
.example {
  // if $vh < $vw
      font-size: 20vh;
  // else font-size === $vw
}
```

*vw will consistently be the maximum value.*

Comment: sass is a precompiler, it has no reference to the state of your vh/vw before it compiles your css output. However if you used javascript to dynamically grab the values for comparison to generate and define the desired font-size on the root element after document load, and use REM units on all of the children then you could come closer to your desired result.

Comment: This is exactly what I feared. I will be using JavaScript as a last resort. Maybe there is a "smart" sassy-solution. I tried to fiddle around with the calc() function, but unfortunately without success. Still hoping there is a calculation that would handle my desired result.